# Koma-Script scrbook remove indention of entries within lof and lot

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, koma-script, scrbook

I'm trying to remove the indention of the entries within the list of figures and list of tables. Thus that the entries (here the entry `0.1 Test`) are left aligned with the header.

However, I can't find an option for this. Someone an idea?

MWE:

```
\documentclass [] {scrbook}

\begin{document}

\listoftables 

\cleardoubleemptypage

\begin{table}[tbp]
    \centering
    \caption[Test]{Test}
    \label{tab:t}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe `listof=flat` does what you want:

```
\documentclass[
  listof=flat
]{scrbook}
\begin{document}

\listoftables 

\cleardoubleemptypage
\begin{table}[tbp]
    \centering
    \captionabove{Test}
    \label{tab:t}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `listof=flat` the needed `numwidth` for the numbers is measured. So it needs an additional run.

---

**Update:**

I would still suggest to use option `listof=flat`. But since **version 3.20** you can also set the `indent` for `table` and `figure` in the lists directly using:

```
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt]{tocline}{table}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt]{tocline}{figure}
```

Then the default `numwidth` (2.3em) will not be changed.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[
  captions=tableheading
]{scrbook}[2016/05/10]
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt]{tocline}{table}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[indent=0pt]{tocline}{figure}
\begin{document}
\listoftables
\cleardoubleemptypage
\begin{table}[tbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Test}
  \label{tab:t}
  \begin{tabular}{cccc}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Remark: Use `\captionabove` instead `\caption` if the caption is a heading. Then you get the correct space between the caption and the table. If all table captions are headings it is also possible to use the class option `captions=tableheading` and `\caption`. See the documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}}
\let\l@table\l@figure
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\listoftables

\cleardoubleemptypage

\begin{table}[tbp]
    \centering
    \caption[Test]{Test}
    \label{tab:t}
        \begin{tabular}{cccc}
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a difference to the easier switch `listof=flat` esdd mentioned above or are there any side effects `listof=flat` cause which I don't see so far?

Comment: Well the option listof=flat is the official method (unlike me Elke remembers all these options), but I don't know if there is any difference in the result -- the code of the KOMA-classes are not very readable, tons of "ifcase x then" which are difficult to follow up.